# Quartz job in Grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

consider the following codes:

```
class MyJob {  
    def execute() {
        println "Hello at->"+new Date()
    }
}
```

when I run this code it starts running every minute without assigning any trigger. How could I disable this property? I want to start this job whenever I make my trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable the default trigger and not assign a trigger at startup then you just need an empty triggers closure in the class.

```
class MyJob {
    static triggers = { }

    ...
}
```

That will assign the closure's triggers, which are none, to the job instead of the default trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit vague what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to execute this when you 'create' a trigger, then you actually don't need to put this in a cron job.

However if you want to activate this after a certain event. Then you would still create a trigger, but have some sort of check before execution. Ex.

```
class MyJob {
   static triggers = { .... create the schedule      

   def execute() {
     // instead of create a trigger, you create a temp file that would allow/prevent
     // the execution
     def runIt = new File(runFile.txt)  
     if (runIt.exists()) {
        println "Hello at->"+new Date()
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that whenever you make a job, the default trigger will be assigned to it automatically. when I add my own trigger, this job will be affected by both triggers. My main question is how to disable the default trigger? It should be something about the settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, you would first install the quartz config:

`grails install-quartz-config`

Then disable auto startup:

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = false
    jdbcStore = false
}
```

Then [dynamically schedule the job](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html) inside your application:

```
// creates cron trigger;
MyJob.schedule(String cronExpression, Map params?)
//  creates simple trigger: repeats job repeatCount+1 times with delay of repeatInterval milliseconds;
MyJob.schedule(Long repeatInterval, Integer repeatCount?, Map params?) )

// schedules one job execution to the specific date;
MyJob.schedule(Date scheduleDate, Map params?)

//schedules job's execution with a custom trigger;
MyJob.schedule(Trigger trigger)

// force immediate execution of the job.
MyJob.triggerNow(Map params?)
```

Comment: I did the settings and job scheduling before, but it seems that it disables all triggers. Nothing happens (quartz {
    autoStartup = false
    jdbcStore = false
})

Comment: It does disable all triggers... that's where the 'dynamically schedule the job' part comes in.  Maybe you should clarify your question.